# accessing DOM elements of parent view from Ajax-loaded child view in ASP.NET MVC with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Up until now, I never had a problem with accessing DOM elements of a parent view from a child view. But this is the first time that I actually load in a partial view via ajax, and under these circumstances I don't seem to be able to access any elements of the parent view with JQuery.

Which is a problem, because the child view is really just a selection table that's supposed to update the parent and then go away again. I could do this with a select box, but with a really lengthy list I consider that extremely suboptimal. Also, I don't want to have to send half the database up front without it ever getting used.

I did some searching, and in the case of Iframes, window.parent.document seems to be an answer, but this isn't an Iframe. Frankly I'm not quite sure what the problem is, I didn't expect the script to opperate in another scope. But I don't seem to be able to access anything from the parent view, not even other scripts. How can I get access to the parent view's DOM?

This is the parent view (it's in itself already a partial view, but not loaded by ajax, and it contains all the elements I'm interested in)

```
    <script>
    //register events for choose and create button
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#choosecustomerbtn").click(function (e)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_CustomersTable", "Camera")',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $('#customer_table_cont').html(data);
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>



<div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10" id="customer_company_label">
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Company)</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Honorific):</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10" id="customer_honorific_label">
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Honorific)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email):</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10" id="customer_email_label">
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-default" id="choosecustomerbtn">
            Kunde wählen
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <!--div that will be used to render the customer table if it is needed-->
    <div id="customers_table_cont"></div>
</div>
```

Basically it just lists a customers company, an email address and the person to contact. It's part of a much wider structure that doesn't play into the problem at hand. All I want to do is that if somebody has to assign another customer, they click the #choosecustomerbtn and get a table from where they can comfortably select the new customer and have the labels updated. So when the button is clicked, this view is loaded:

```
@model IEnumerable<qcic_frontend.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel>

@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script>
    //register click event for table
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        //don't register table header (first row)
        isheader = true;
        $('tr').each(function () 
        {
            if (!isheader)
            {
                $(this).click(function (e)
                {
                    //replace the labels in the customer view
                    $('#customer_company_label').html($(this).children('.customer_company').text());
                    $('#customer_honorific_label').html($(this).children('.customer_honorific').text());
                    $('#customer_email_label').html($(this).children('.customer_email').text());
                    //remove the table again for better oversight
//                    $('#customers_table_cont').html("");
                });
            }
            isheader = false;
        });

</script>


<table class="table table-hover ajax_table" id="customers_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Honorific)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach(var i in Model)
        {
            <tr id="@i.ID">
                <td class="customer_company">@Html.DisplayFor(item => i.Company)</td>
                <td class="customer_honorific">@Html.DisplayFor(item => i.Honorific)</td>
                <td class="customer_email">@Html.DisplayFor(item => i.Email)</td>
            </tr>
        } 
    </tbody>   
</table>
```

So when a table row gets clicked, the labels should update and the table go away again.

Comment: why don't you share some of your code ?

Comment: I thought there was probably just some conceptual problem I'm dealing with, and the code is a bit messy from all the trial and error I did, but I'll put it up right away if it helps.

Comment: Scripts should never go in partial views. Put them in the main view of the layout.